# ReactJS component update on array update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a basic 'wrapper' component which contains child 'item' components

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
       };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Items count- {this.state.items.length}
                    {this.state.items.map(function (item, i) {
                        <Item itemId={item.itemId} />
                    })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}




class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) { super(props); }
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="item">{this.props.itemId}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Do I call `setState({ "items":[{ "itemId": 22 }] });` to update items in UI?

Want to add/remove 'item' and get UI updated accordingly.

Comment: You need to concatenate the old array with the new item using setState

Comment: Actually, I'm so geeking on `React.JS` but your question is not obvious, please leave some description, What actually you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

For updates, you want to do something like the following...

```
// Update item
this.setState({ "items":this.state.items.map(function(item) {
    if (item.itemId !== 22) return item;
    // update item here

    // remember to return item
    return item
  })
});

// Remove item
this.setState({ "items":this.state.items.filter(item => {
  return item.itemId !== 22
})
})

// Add item
this.setState({ "items": this.state.items.concat(newItem)
})
```

I suggest putting these into React class methods though.

import React from 'react';

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          items: []
     };
     this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)
     this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this)
     this.updateItem = this.updateItem.bind(this)
  }
  addItem (item) {
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.concat(item)
    })
  }
  updateItem(id, updatedItem) {
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.map(function (item) {
        if (item.itemId !== id) return item;
        return updatedItem;
      })
    })
  }
  removeItem(id) {
    this.setState({
      items: this.state.items.filter(function(item) {
        return item.itemId !== id
      })
    })
  }
  render() {
      return (
          <div>Items count- {this.state.items.length}
            {this.state.items.map(function (item, i) {
                <Item itemId={item.itemId} />
            })}
          </div>
      );
  }
}




class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { super(props); }
  render() {
      return (
          <div class="item">{this.props.itemId}</div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

State is not mutable, so the code you've shown there will replace `items` with an array with one object.  If you'd like to add/remove from the array, you'll first need to copy the array somehow , and replace with the new one. You should use the function argument of setState for that. Ex:

```
this.setState(function (currentState) {
  return {items: currentState.concat({itemId: 22})}
});
```

Comment: Nice! Can you show another version not using the spread operator?

Comment: on just use `this.setState({ items: this.state.items.concat({itemId: 22}) })`

Comment: Updated to not use spread operator. You should use the function version of setState though, since your next state is dependent on the previous.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you `add` and `remove` to and from the state items array:

```js
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
  }
  addItems = (id) => {
  // copies all current items and adds a new one
  this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, {itemId: id}]
  })
  }
  removeItems = (id) => {
  const newItemList = this.state.items.filter((item) => item.itemId !== id)
  this.setState({items: newItemList
  })
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
    <div>Items count - {this.state.items.length}
      
      <button onClick={() => this.addItems(this.state.items.length + 1)}>Add Item</button>
      
      
      </div>
      {
        this.state.items.map((item) => { 
        return (
          <Item key={item.itemId} itemId={item.itemId} removeItems={this.removeItems} />
        )
        })
      } 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper />, document.getElementById('root'))


class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="item">test{this.props.itemId} <button onClick={() => this.props.removeItems(this.props.itemId)}>Remove Item</button></div>;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```